how to draw line curves?
I am trying to draw curves in the coordinate system but not sure how to do. I am using draw[in=,out=] but that does not give me the curve I want. Please see curves in my attached figure
\begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[->,thick] (-10,0)--(-5,0) node[right]{r};
            \draw[->,thick] (-10,-3)--(-10,3) node[above]{t};
            \draw[red,dashed,very thick] (-8.5,-3)--(-8.5,3) node at (-8.8,-0.25) {2m};
            \draw[blue,very thick] (-5,-3)--(-7,3);
            \draw[blue,very thick] (-6,-3) to [in=20,out=125](-8,2);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[->,thick] (-2,0)--(3,0) node [right]{r};
        \draw[->,thick] (-2,-3)--(-2,3) node[above]{t};
        \draw[red,dashed,very thick] (-0.5,-3)--(-0.5,3) node at (-0.8,-0.25) {2m};
    \end{tikzpicture}



Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Replace -- in the \draw statements by to[out=,in=] where you specify both angles. // Use pos again to put some cones along those curves ;-)
